Kotlin Frontend Compiler Plugin: Do I really have to annotate every entity that I want to process?
I was able to develop a Kotlin backend compiler plugin as an IrGenerationExtension that modifies code during compilation using an IrElementTransformerVoidWithContext.
This was achieved mostly by following the great blog post series by Brian Norman.
There was no need to change anything in the original source code that is processed by the compiler plugin.
Now, for a research prototype, I wanted to work on another compiler plugin, this time a Kotlin frontend compiler plugin.
As a start, I just wanted to achieve to add a println statement at the start of every method.
And this is where I am struggling: Is there any way to visit every method in a Kotlin frontend compiler plugin?
I found following documentation on Github:

Right now, the only way to communicate between user code and plugin is to mark something in code with some annotation, so the plugin will look at this annotation and do its magic.

This shrinks my expectations, as it seems frontend plugins are currently just another kind of annotation processor and are "useless" if I do not want to change the existing code that should be processed by the compiler plugin.
TL;DR: Is there any way to process every method in a Kotlin frontend compiler plugin without the need to annotate the methods (or their classes) in the source code?
